# IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.5 Project View Dotted Lines

Tags: intellij-idea, view, project, intellij-14, appearance

So my question is basically: How do I get rid of the dotted lines? I compared it with other IntelliJ users and I'm the only one that has these lines!

Thanks for helping out!

[image: Here is a screenshot of my project view]

Comment: This is theme specific. You probably have Windows theme set in Settings/Appearance & Behavior/Appearance. Change it to IntelliJ or Darcula to get rid of it.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!